# Geoip plugin not working with filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I have recently installed geoip plugin but it is not doing anything with the data being shipped with filebeat.
However when I manually index some document, it works as expected. My filebeat configuration is default. Do I need to do something more to make it work with filebeat ? 
[image]

Comment: which version of Filebeat and ES are you running? Can you show your filebeat configuration file?

Comment: @val Everything is 6.2, added config file.

Comment: What do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/templates`?